# How to create a RSS Link?

Tags: xml, rss, feedburner

I have been tried to create a RSS link to an android application, I have been tested this link and working perfectly: http://feeds.feedburner.com/androidcentral?format=xml , but even following the steps in feedburner I don't know how to create a similar, and even when I just add ?format=xml in the end of the mine still my link doesn't work....this is my blog any idea how to fix this issue guys???
http://newalfa.blogspot.com.br/

PS if you are going to give a negative point in this issue, could you to say why before?

Comment: According to the auto-discovery links in the `<head>` section of your blog's homepage, your RSS feed should be `http://newalfa.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss`. However, while it looks like a mostly valid feed, it does have [some validation failures](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnewalfa.blogspot.com%2Ffeeds%2Fposts%2Fdefault%3Falt%3Drss) that might be causing you a problem. Can you please define "doesn't work" a little more carefully for us, please? What are you expecting to happen, and what's happing that's different from that?

Comment: it's ok, mate. Sorry my english is really poor. Well, I am working on a android application and when I use theses links the application android works perfectly -  http://feeds.feedburner.com/androidcentral?format=xml, http://g1.globo.com/tecnologia/noticia/2012/11/siga-o-g1-por-rss.html .
But when I create my own the screen doesn't show me nothing, then I am trying to create one that works.
thank in advance, mate!

Answer (score 0):

It's a different URL on Blogspot. This appears to work:
http://newalfa.blogspot.com.br/feeds/posts/default

Comment: I am sorry, mate, but it didn't work :/ ... this  http://feeds.feedburner.com/androidcentral works,but I don't know what is different from the mine like this: http://feeds.feedburner.com/newalfajesus I have beem tried too many times differents, but still nothing.... :/